# Limit the depth of children that threaded finds

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a nested table using the `Tree` behavior. I want to find records for the top parents and one level down.

I've been using the `$this->Category->find('threaded');` but it returns the top and all children.

Is there a way to limit the depth of recursion for finding threaded records?

Answer (score 3):

We can limit the results by adding conditions to find('threaded') query. We either want records that are top level (`parent_id = NULL`) or records where the `parent_id` is that of a top level record.

```
$this->Model->find('threaded', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'OR' => array(
                'parent_id' => NULL,
                'parent_id IN (SELECT id from your_table_here WHERE parent_id IS NULL)',
            )
        )
));
```

Comment: +1 for showing me how to do an inner `SELECT` in a Cake condition.